# "new" Keyword In Java Lambda Method Reference

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, method-reference

I've seen a lot of methods where a new class is instantiated in a lambda method reference but can't seem to understand why. When is the `new` keyword needed in a method reference?

For example, the following passes compilation:

```
UnaryOperator<String>stringToUpperCase = String::toUpperCase;
```

But this doesn't:

```
UnaryOperator<String>stringToUpperCase = new String()::toUpperCase;
```

Comment: a new String in upper case is still just a blank string, so `s -> ""` will do the same thing

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`String::toUpperCase` is a method reference that can be applied to any `String` instance.

`new String()::toUpperCase` is a method reference that can be applied to a specific `String` instance (the instance created by `new String()`).

Since `UnaryOperator<String>` expects a method that takes a `String` and returns a `String`, `String::toUpperCase` fits (since you can apply it on a `String` and get the upper case version of that `String`).

On the other hand, `new String()::toUpperCase` doesn't fit `UnaryOperator<String>`, since it is executed on an already specified `String`, so you can't pass another `String` instance to it.

It can, however, by assigned to a `Supplier<String>`, since it simply supplies an empty `String` instance:

```
Supplier<String> emptyStringToUpperCase = new String()::toUpperCase;
```

This is similar to:

```
Supplier<String> emptyStringToUpperCase = () -> new String().toUpperCase();
```

while this:

```
UnaryOperator<String> stringToUpperCase = String::toUpperCase;
```

is similar to:

```
UnaryOperator<String> stringToUpperCase = s -> s.toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 5):

There are four kinds of method references as shown below and your type falls in the second category, but `UnaryOperator<String>` essentially needs to represent a method which accepts **any** String argument and returns a String. However, the non-working method reference that you have used is actually working on a **particular** String object (i.e. not **any** String object)

[image]

Refer:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html

Comment: Strictly speaking, `new String()::toUpperCase` is indeed a method reference, of the third kind (`new String()` is an object which has the `toUpperCase` method). It doesn't take arguments, but returns a `String`. It could be used as a `Supplier<String>`. But it is a very complicated way to say `() -> ""`.

Comment: @glglgl Actually, the second type, right?

Comment: With 0-based counting even the 1st :P